# Is the this constant incorrect?

Tags: c++, timer, arduino, atmel

I am currently reading an application note from [atmel](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8017.pdf), where i am currently trying to understand the [code](https://github.com/plastiv/stepper-motor-controller/blob/master/%20stepper-motor-controller%20--username%20plastiv%40gmail.com/code/speed_cntr.h). The code generated a trapezoidal ramp,for controlling a stepper motor.

One thing I don't understand by the code, is a constant set to be

```
// Timer/Counter 1 running on 3,686MHz / 8 = 460,75kHz (2,17uS). (T1-FREQ 460750)
#define T1_FREQ 1382400
```

I am not sure i understand why the value is 1382400, rather than 460750, since the clock frequency prescaled by 8 is 460750... So why is it 1382400? Am I missing something?

.h file

```
/*This file has been prepared for Doxygen automatic documentation generation.*/
/*! \file *********************************************************************
 *
 * \brief Header file for speed_cntr.c.
 *
 * - File:               speed_cntr.h
 * - Compiler:           IAR EWAAVR 4.11A
 * - Supported devices:  All devices with a 16 bit timer can be used.
 *                       The example is written for ATmega48
 * - AppNote:            AVR446 - Linear speed control of stepper motor
 *
 * \author               Atmel Corporation: http://www.atmel.com \n
 *                       Support email: avr@atmel.com
 *
 * $Name: RELEASE_1_0 $
 * $Revision: 1.2 $
 * $RCSfile: speed_cntr.h,v $
 * $Date: 2006/05/08 12:25:58 $
 *****************************************************************************/

#ifndef SPEED_CNTR_H
#define SPEED_CNTR_H

/*! \brief Holding data used by timer interrupt for speed ramp calculation.
 *
 *  Contains data used by timer interrupt to calculate speed profile.
 *  Data is written to it by move(), when stepper motor is moving (timer
 *  interrupt running) data is read/updated when calculating a new step_delay
 */
typedef struct {
  //! What part of the speed ramp we are in.
  unsigned char run_state : 3;
  //! Direction stepper motor should move.
  unsigned char dir : 1;
  //! Peroid of next timer delay. At start this value set the accelration rate.
  unsigned int step_delay;
  //! What step_pos to start decelaration
  unsigned int decel_start;
  //! Sets deceleration rate.
  signed int decel_val;
  //! Minimum time delay (max speed)
  signed int min_delay;
  //! Counter used when accelerateing/decelerateing to calculate step_delay.
  signed int accel_count;
} speedRampData;

/*! \Brief Frequency of timer1 in [Hz].
 *
 * Modify this according to frequency used. Because of the prescaler setting,
 * the timer1 frequency is the clock frequency divided by 8.
 */
// Timer/Counter 1 running on 3,686MHz / 8 = 460,75kHz (2,17uS). (T1-FREQ 460750)
#define T1_FREQ 1382400

//! Number of (full)steps per round on stepper motor in use.
#define FSPR 200

#ifdef HALFSTEPS
  #define SPR (FSPR*2)
  #pragma message("[speed_cntr.c] *** Using Halfsteps ***")
#endif
#ifdef FULLSTEPS
  #define SPR FSPR
  #pragma message("[speed_cntr.c] *** Using Fullsteps ***")
#endif
#ifndef HALFSTEPS
  #ifndef FULLSTEPS
    #error FULLSTEPS/HALFSTEPS not defined!
  #endif
#endif

// Maths constants. To simplify maths when calculating in speed_cntr_Move().
#define ALPHA (2*3.14159/SPR)                    // 2*pi/spr
#define A_T_x100 ((long)(ALPHA*T1_FREQ*100))     // (ALPHA / T1_FREQ)*100
#define T1_FREQ_148 ((int)((T1_FREQ*0.676)/100)) // divided by 100 and scaled by 0.676
#define A_SQ (long)(ALPHA*2*10000000000)         // ALPHA*2*10000000000
#define A_x20000 (int)(ALPHA*20000)              // ALPHA*20000

// Speed ramp states
#define STOP  0
#define ACCEL 1
#define DECEL 2
#define RUN   3

void speed_cntr_Move(signed int step, unsigned int accel, unsigned int decel, unsigned int speed);
void speed_cntr_Init_Timer1(void);
static unsigned long sqrt(unsigned long v);
unsigned int min(unsigned int x, unsigned int y);

//! Global status flags
extern struct GLOBAL_FLAGS status;

#endif
```

Comment: ... Fun fact,maybe something in to it?

Comment: I guess there is not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*! \Brief Frequency of timer1 in [Hz].
 *
```

The comment tells you to modify T1_FREQ to your needs.

```
 * Modify this according to frequency used. Because of the prescaler setting,
 * the timer1 frequency is the clock frequency divided by 8.
 */
```

This line gives you an example for calculation. It's just an example. They could have used completely different numbers if the wanted to. They won't change a general example every time they use different prescalers or frequencies.

```
// Timer/Counter 1 running on 3,686MHz / 8 = 460,75kHz (2,17uS). (T1-FREQ 460750)
```

This line is the line you should change if needed. 1382400 is what they used in their code. If you need 460750 in your case, then replace the number...

```
#define T1_FREQ 1382400
```

Comment: Thanks. I really hoped that was the case.